# ODOO 8 - How to publish website?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-website

ODOO 8 - How to launch a website after designing it with website builder?

For Example:

Example.com - Runs on ODOO.

I created a small website using website builder app but I don't know how to publish it. If I open a Example.com, I am getting login page of ODOO and not the website which I created using the app.

Only if I logged in and click on the website button it showing me the website.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just you just refer the below link from the Odoo forum

https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-do-i-publish-my-odoo-website-onto-my-domain-name-58635

I hope my answer may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

- I have installed odoo on my synology server.
- Installed website builder indeed
- I droped default database odoo8 for avoiding to land on: odoo8 page where you choose your database and can admin others. You should have only one database! It's very important!
  ( I don't know how to deal with multiple database but odoo expert might have the solution... I'm not...)

I put an alias on my webhosting provider consol (hostarea for me) for redirecting on my synology server odoo webpage.
 **192.xxx.x.x:8069** IP adress and port corresponding to odoo service on my synology server.

It workes for me and I'm very happy because I spent 2 days for solving this issue.
Hope my experience would help some.
Sincerly yours Gabe